# Ethernet is connected to android device. I am able to ping 8.8.8.8 from adb shell, but not able to browse internet

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, connection-issues

Ethernet is connected to android device. I am able to ping 8.8.8.8 from adb shell, but not able to browse internet. The Ethernet connection is doesn't show up on notification bar.

I have tried setting up STATIC IP and tried updating route table, but no luck.

Comment: What device is that and are you router configurations allow static IP addresses?

Comment: Yes, STATIC IP configured on router side.
Device: Nexus 5